# Why is my application not updating when I rerun it?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am writing an application on android studio. the build was successful, however when I run it on my phone then it does not show the updates that I made. My phone is a model: pixel_3a_API_30_x86.

Comment: This should normally work. Please explain step by step what you are doing.

Comment: The application starts with showing "Hello World", however when I move it or change it to something else, it still shows "Hello world" with no change.

Comment: @AmichaiTaub, are you sure you change text in appropriate activity/fragment? Maybe something is wrong in a project and you mixed a class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to press File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it did not work